# EditText appears in Design but not in the real apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext

This is the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text:"
   />

<EditText
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="type ur text here"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/label"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the Design, on Android Studio, both the `TextView` and the `EditText` can be seen, but after compiling only the `TextView` is visible.

Why?

Screenshots

Design:

[image: Design]

Apk:

[image]

Thanks

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post the Screen Shot also

Comment: Try to change the theme in your Style file. You can share your style file code here so that I can assist you.

Comment: Change  `android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/label"` to     `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label"`,     `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label"` to     `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label"` ,     `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/label" to`    `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/label"`

Comment: @Piyush didn't work , same result

Comment: What is your theme style ? It must be worked.

Comment: Default style, it's just a brand new app

Comment: Remove `android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/label"`

Comment: @JaredRummler EditText is been displayed but with different baseline

Comment: **copy pasted your code and run app. it worked like a charm.** maybe you have any other problem. try to test it on any other device

Comment: @AliAhmed worked on API 26! So what's wrong with API 23?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text:"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="type ur text here"
        />
</LinearLayout
```

Comment: Thks, but I have to use a RelativeLayout

Comment: May be it is because of the style u have used

Comment: Try to change the style

Comment: Same result, removing alignBaseline makes EditText visible but it's not the expected result

Comment: I tried your code , its working for me. Which device are you using?

Comment: The AVD Nexus S API 23, what are you using?

Comment: by removing alignBaseline worked for me..I am using android 5.1 and 6. What is your desired result?

Comment: Give textHintColor

Comment: try android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label"

Comment: Tried on android 6.0 virtual and real devices but didn't work. These changes on EditText make it appearing: `match_parent` to `wrap_content` ; removing `alignBaseline`, adding `android:textSize="100dp" ` or changing `EditText` to `TextView` , but still don't understand why